# Fluent Assertions ShouldAllBeEquivalentTo

Tags: c#, unit-testing, fluent-assertions

I'm not sure if an old version of FluentAssertions had this or not but I'd like to compare a collection to another collection.  I have a dto like so:

```
public class UserDTO
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Username { get; set; }
}
```

I have two lists Id like to compare.

```
 List<UserDTO> createdUsers = this.GetCreatedUser();
 var expectedResults = this.dbContext.Users.Top(10);
```

The closest thing I see to should all be equivalent is:

```
 createdUsers.Should().AllBeEquivalentTo(expectedResults)
```

but when I try to pass my exclusions, it seems to be operating providing me exlusions for the list instead of the entity itself.

I would like to compare two list of these excluding the Id property.  I could of sworn there was a function called `ShouldAllBeEquivalentTo` which took in options to allow exluding,

```
createdUsers.ShouldAllBeEquivalentTo(expectedResults, o => o.Excluding(x => x.Id);
```

How can I compare collections while excluding properties in the comparison?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Documentation suggests the following when it comes to exclusions with Collections and Dictionaries

```
createdUsers.Should().BeEquivalentTo(expectedResults, options => options.Excluding(_ => _.Id));
```

Quote from documentation:

> to assert that all instances of OrderDto are structurally equal to a single object:

```
orderDtos.Should().AllBeEquivalentTo(singleOrder);
```

Reference [Object graph comparison: Collections and Dictionaries](https://fluentassertions.com/objectgraphs/)

Comment: Interesting,  I was working on such an old version with my last company, things must have changed a bit, Thanks!

Comment: This is correct. `BeAllEquivalentTo` would compare each object in the collection with the same single object.

Comment: @johnny5 Yes, in the latest Major version of FA, `ShouldBeEquivalentTo()` was moved to `Should().BeEquivalentTo()` as stated on Dennis's blog: https://www.continuousimprover.com/2018/02/fluent-assertions-50-best-unit-test.html#upgrading-tips